# Trouble port forwarding a cellular router

Tags: port-forwarding, cellular

I am trying to port forward an ATT Homebase cellular hotspot modem router model Z700 to handle a security system DVR for remote access. Does anyone have knowledge on this? Thanks in advance if anyone does!

Comment: You should check if this is doable - a lot of cellphone providers use Carrier Grade NAT, which would make doing this impossible.  (You could work around it using a VPN though)

Comment: Did you consult the user manual for the router?.....https://www.att.com/devicehowto/tutorial.html#!/interactive/id/interactive_1179150?make=ATT&model=HomeBaseZ700A